# What does the idiom "to be known for" mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Ok, see this sentence "*London is known for Big Ben*".

So, does the idiom "*to be known for*" mean "*to be well-known for*" or "*to be famous for*".

Like "*London is known (famous) for Big Ben*"?

I could not see any website say that "*to be known for*" = "*to be famous for*"

What does the idiom "**to be known for**" mean?

Comment: Yes, "to be well-known for" is exactly what it means. (And as soon as I can find a source other than "I'm a native English speaker," I'll include it.)

Comment: See also *renowned for*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get yourself familiarized with the preposition, [for](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for). As you can see in Merriam-Webster, "for" means "because of" that explains the reason for a verb or an adjective.

London is known for Big Ben. = London is known because of Big Ben. 
London is famous (renowned) for Big Ben. = London is famous (renowned) because of Big Ben.

Known/renowned/famous are synonyms.

"For" is one of the most important prepositions and conjunctions. It has many crucial meanings you have to learn to better your English.

Comment: 'Known' might also suggest 'infamous', so I'd be a bit reluctant to call them synonyms.

Comment: @JHCL Fair point.But sometimes famous is also used for infamous or notorious. [Editors for the dictionaries must be aware of this](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/famous-and-well-known)